# Jquery checking if all fields are correct not working

Tags: jquery

Im trying to check if all fields are true so I made a function, "where"is the input field and "check" is wheter is true or not.

```
check_fields(where,check){
var fname = false;
    var lname = false;
    var email = false;
    var email2 = false;
    var pass = false;
    var pass2 = false;
    var gender = false;
if(where == "fname" && check == true){
        fname = true;
        alert("a");
    }else{
        fname = false;
    }

    if(where == "lname" && check == true){
        lname = true;
        alert("b");
    }else{
        lname = false;
    }

    if(where == "email" && check == true){
        email = true;
        alert("b");
    }else{
        email = false;
    }

    if(where == "pass" && check == true){
        pass = true;
        alert("c");
    }else{
        pass = false;
    }

    if(where == "gender" && check == true){
        gender = true;
alert("d");
        if(fname == true && lname == true && email == true && pass == true){
        form_ispass();
        alert("HI");
        }
    }else{
        gender = false;
    }
}
```

it does alert from, a, b, b, c but when I check the gender it does alert d. However it doesnt alert HI even all of the fields are set to true.

Answer (score 0):

Your final check is inside your `gender` condition.  Move it outside:

```
if(where == "gender" && check == true){
    gender = true;
    alert("d");
}else{
    gender = false;
}

if(fname == true && lname == true && email == true && pass == true){
    form_ispass();
    alert("HI");
}
```

Comment: already did that, I just moved it inside because the alert of the gender works so, i thought it will alert HI. Thanks though but it didnt work.

Comment: what does `form_ispass()` do?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue, made a global variable for of every input and when it met what I want i set it to true and everytime you type something into the input you always call the:

```
function check_fields(){
if(fname == true && lname == true && email == true && pass == true){
    alert("HI");
    }
}
```